# A little number riddle

Tags: lateral-thinking

*Try your best to solve the puzzle below GOOD LUCK!!!*

```
Explain why

1=0 
2=0
3=0 
4=0
10=0

And

7=1
8=1
9=1

But 

5=2
6=2
11=2
12=2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> The number of letters used in Roman numerals in the spelling of the number

> Taken from dictionary.com:
>   The Roman numeral system uses only seven symbols: I, V, X, L, C, D, and M. I represents the number 1, V represents 5, X is 10, L is 50, C is 100, D is 500, and M is 1,000. Different arrangements of these seven symbols represent different numbers.
>  
>  Thus:
>  
>  ONE 0 letters used in Roman numerals
>  TWO 0 letters
>  THREE 0 letters
>  FOUR 0 letters
>  TEN 0 letters
>  
>  SE**V**EN 1 letter: V
>  E**I**GHT 1 letter: I
>  N**I**NE 1 letter: I
>  
>  F**IV**E 2 letters: IV
>  S**IX** 2 letters: IX
>  E**L**E**V**EN 2 letters: LV
>  TWE**LV**E 2 letters: LV

Comment: I've been staring at this for 15 solid minutes and you just blew my mind. Thank you.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic The lateral-thinking tag kinda give it off as a non-math problem, and I thought if it's not math it had to be English or some word play. Anyways, you're welcome ;)